# Navigation Property not being updated on db.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have an Edit controller method that takes a `Tool` from an Edit view.

The Tool model contains a `MobileUser` navigation property with name `Holder`, and it also contains a string `HolderName`, that's used to set a holder in the view.

In the controller method I set the `MobileUser` by getting the user with `Tool.HolderName == MobileUser.Name`, but after `db.SaveChanges()` is called the `MobileUser` navigation property is not changes in the database.

My code:

ToolsController.Edit(Tool tool):

```
        int id = db.MobileUsers.Single(x => x.Name == tool.HolderName).Id;
        tool.Holder = db.MobileUsers.Find(id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(tool).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(tool);
```

The Holder navigation property in Tool class:

```
    public virtual MobileUser Holder { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the entry and save contained within a try catch and see if you get an exception thrown?

Comment: You said that you are getting tool as model from your form but I believe it should be attached to context

Comment: @MichaelStaples I did, and no exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: @Neir0 I tried attaching before saving, but still no dice.

Comment: Can you show us how you configured the relationship between them? This is a common problem when you work with properties and not foreign keys, specially in disconnected scenarios. Are you fetching the tool from database as well before calling Saving Changes?

Comment: @jpgrassi The tool is passed as an argument, it's not fetched. The MobileUser however, is fetched from the database.

Comment: So I believe that’s the issue then. Try fetching it also just to try out.

Comment: the Entry() method attaches the object to the DbSet, but not the navigation properties. This is one of EF's principles, because then a call to ChangeTracking would be required. this also mean that only the tool object is attached to the DbContext, while Holder is not in the DbContext (at least not in modified state) so no changes will be persisted in the database.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro How would I persist the navigation properties as well?

Comment: you'll have to set the state of these entries to EntityState.Modified as well. .Add and .AddRange will attach and set the state of object and navigation properties, the Entry method will only attach the object without referenced objects.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Setting the navigation properties as modified does not fix the problem. I don't think .Add() and .AddRange() are relevant since I'm not adding anything, I'm just editing.

Comment: if really nothing got updated, you'd get an OptimisticConcurrencyException or an EntityCommandExecutionException. Which code do you use to update the object, do you call SaveChanges afterwards (on the correct DbContext instance) and which method do you use to check if changes were made persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up and used GraphDiff instead. Works very well and I recommend it if anyone runs into this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First the requisite don't use entity models in your controllers speech (use ViewModels) and second show your models. IAC, try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Tool tool):

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // If you want to update fields in tool.Holder, do something like this:
        var newHolder = tool.Holder;  // save changes from view.
        // Fetch the current Holder from database
        tool.Holder = db.MobileUsers.Single(x => x.Name == tool.HolderName);
        // Replace the changed properties. Many ways to do this. I like Automapper.
        tool.Holder.Field1 = newHolder.Field1;
        tool.Holder.Field2 = newHolder.Field2;
        // etc.

        db.Entry(tool).State = EntityState.Modified;
        // Below not needed since you getched it into the context
        // db.Entry(tool.Holder).State = EntityState.Modified;  // Need to set child state as well
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(tool);
}
```

In a ViewModel scenario, your POST would fetch the tool and holder, map the changes in and save without exposing your entire entity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the state of the child model as well, but it still does not work.

Comment: What change are you expecting that is not occurring?

Comment: That `tool.Holder` persists. The database doesn't really save the changes made.

Comment: Changes to the Holder object are not going to persist with the code you have shown because you are fetching it from the database and not mapping the changes back in as you might in a ViewModel scenario. You should, however, see a relationship from Tool to Holder (the old version). See edit.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear with what I'm trying to achieve. I'm just trying to update `tool.Holder`, not edit the object itself. For example if there are 2 holders Viggo and Steve, and Steve is the current holder of the tool in question, I'd like to change the holder to Viggo. I'm not trying to change the properties of Steve. Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: Well that is a much simpler and common use case. All you really have to do is expose the Foreign Key (HolderId, etc) inside Tool and then set it in the POST. No need to fetch and mess with the nav property.